# Difference between ()() and (,) when declaring array (vb.net)

Tags: arrays, vb.net

What's difference when declaring array like this:

```
Dim Data()() as byte
```

and

```
Dim Data(,) as byte
```

the first difference I saw, was: I can redim the first one Data using

```
Redim Data(20,30)
```

It throws a null-ref ex. But it's OK for the second Data.
So what's difference? In my book says that the two syntax are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is how you declare a jagged array.

> **To declare a multidimensional array variable**
>
> ```
>     Dim atmospherePressures(,,,) As Short
> ```
>
> **To declare a jagged array variable**
>
> ```
>     Dim inquiriesByYearMonthDay()()() As Byte
> ```

[Ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x397t1yt%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The first one is jagged array (array of arrays), while the second is so-called rectangular array (single array with multidimesional "syntax-sugar").

> In my book says that the two syntax are the same.

That's plain wrong.

Comment: OK, so I have things to talk to my teacher about that book he gives me